# Any way to add more than one text entry to select fields

Tags: entities

In a form that a site user (i.e. not an administrator) fills out I want to have a section like this (the "[ ]" represents a checkbox in the form):

**Certifications**

[ ] Type 1 Certification

[ ] Type 2 Certification

[ ] Type 3 Certification

[ ] Other Type 3 Certifications [text box entry]

[ ] Type 4 Certification

[ ] Type 5 Certifications

[ ] Other Certifications [text box entry]

So the user would check as many of these as apply to them, and if they had a different Type 3 Certification than the one that was listed, they would check the "Other Type 3 Certification" checkbox AND fill out the text box with the type of Certification that wasn't listed.

And they would also have the option of checking the last text box and typing in other types of certifications in that text field.

I found Select or Other (https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other), but it doesn't appear to allow for two text options.

Perhaps I should simply do the list of options with Select or Other, put the Type 3 option last in the list, and add Other Certifications as a separate field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In my opinion**, the Select Or Other module works with field groups or something. It should allow one "other" value per group. You can do like this:

---

**GROUP GENERAL**

[ ] Type 1 Certification

[ ] Type 2 Certification

> **GROUP CERTIF 3**
>
> [ ] Type 3 Certification
>
> *[ ] Other Type 3 Certifications [text box entry]*

[ ] Type 4 Certification

[ ] Type 5 Certifications

*[ ] Other Certifications [text box entry]*

---